# Check project build in MVC3 or in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I got a project and I want to know about the project i.e. it is build in Asp.net MVC3 or in Asp.net MVC4? How can I find its build process i.e. made in MVC3 or in MVC4?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Check project references (or bin folder), look for `"System.Web.Mvc"` and open its properties. Then look the `"Version"` property. If it is `4.0.0.0` is MVC 4, if it is `3.0.0.0` is of course MVC 3.

Answer (score 4):

You can get by code:

```
typeof(YourControlller).Assembly.GetName().Version
```